# Detecting json_decode() failure in PHP

Tags: php, json

When using PHP's `json_decode()`, I don't see a way to distinguish between a `NULL` return value indicating a failure in decoding and a correctly decoded `NULL` value:

```
var_dump(json_decode('nonsense')); // returns NULL
var_dump(json_decode(json_encode(NULL))); // also returns NULL
```

And case one doesn't throw an exception. So I'm not sure how to test for a decode failure.

Ideas?

Comment: FYI, technically, a JSON document cannot contain just a null value, so there shouldn't be anything to distinguish them.  PHP is nice enough to extend JSON to include Arrays and scalars like Strings, Numbers, and null, but these are not valid at the top-level in a JSON doc.

Comment: For the information of others, the above is wholly untrue and has never been wholly true: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-3

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You would have to check [**`json_last_error`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) for any JSON parsing errors.

```
json_decode($string);
switch(json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        echo ' - Maximum stack depth exceeded';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        echo ' - Unexpected control character found';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        echo ' - Syntax error, malformed JSON';
    break;
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        echo ' - No errors';
    break;
}
```

Comment: This being new in php 5.3 would explain why i didn't know about it. Thanks for pointing it out. I'll download fresh documentation today.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help.